# phpmyadmin error 500 when trying to view a tablle

Tags: phpmyadmin

I am trying to deploy a symfony infrastructure
Phpmyadmin is showing me an error 500 when i try viewing a table in any database,
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tRos6.jpg)
 it’s not permission issues as i tried root and even when i create a new database i cannot view its table
I tried to modify php.ini to increase memory post and upload max, not working
In var/log/apache2/error.log it’s showing this[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MXYhC.jpg)

Comment: I would start by checking what's wrong with `sql.lib.php` on line 615

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. (1) It's customary to copy and paste the text of error messages here so that others can search for it (also it makes it easier for people to respond to without having to open new browser tabs), (2) Which phpMyAdmin and PHP versions are you using, (3) How have you installed phpMyAdmin (manually through the downloads at phpmyadmin.net, through some package manager, etc), and (4) Did phpMyAdmin work before your changes to `php.ini`?